# How to test built in recursive manner class with mspec/rhino mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, recursion, rhino-mocks, mspec

I have for example class

```
public class Person {
    private Person Parent;
    private string Name;
    public Person(string Name, Person Parent)
    {
        if(Parent == null)
        {
            thrown new ArgumentNullException("Parent");
        }
        this.Parent = Parent;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

How to test if Parent of Person a is equal b, and at the same time, Parent of Person b is null with mspec and rhino mocks? I don't have access to function that in recursive manner populate Parent field, so I can't count its number of invokes, and therefore, level of depression. Is it even possible?

Comment: "I don't have access to function that in recursive manner populate Parent " Are you trying to test a function that you cannot access ? If you want an answer you have to show us your test code, explain the intention of your test and how are you mocking and trying to test...

Comment: I have no access becuase its private. I want make sure that after instance built there is only one level of depression in recursive class.

Comment: And mentioned private function is part of class(builder).